# Usign Google Play Services under Android, how to know if a signed user have already +1 an URL

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I'm developing a game. I'm using Google Play Services for the leader boards and in order to display a +1 button (PlusOneButton) on the front page.

I'm able to detect if the user have made a +1 to my URL by getting private field of the instance of the PlusOneButton, but I'm not very satisfied with that hack.

I have searched the documentation on the Google Developer Website but I haven't found anything related. Using the existing Google Play Service API, is there a documented way to know if a given user have activated a +1 button on a given URL ?

In advance, thanks.